# Definitive guide on when to use Haskell typeclasses?

Tags: haskell, types, functional-programming, typeclass

So, I understand algebraic types and type classes very well, but I'm interested in the software-engineering/best practices side of it.

What is the modern consensus, if any, on typeclasses? Are they evil? Are they handy? Should they be used, and when?

Here's my case-study. I'm writing an RTS-style game, and I have different kinds of "units" (tank, scout, etc.). Say I want to get the max health of each unit. My two thoughts on how to define their types are as follows:

Different constructors of an ADT:

```
data Unit = Scout ... | Tank ...

maxHealth :: Unit -> Int

maxHealth Scout  = 10

maxHealth Tank = 20
```

Typeclass for Unit, each kind is an instance

```
class Unit a where
    maxHealth :: a -> Int

instance Unit Scout where
    maxHealth scout = 10

instance Unit Tank where
    maxHealth tank = 20
```

Obviously, there is going to be many more fields and functions in the final product. (For example, each unit will have a different position, etc. so not all of the functions will be constant).

The trick is, there might be some functions that make sense for some units, but not others. For example, every unit will have a getPosition function, but a tank might have a getArmour function, which doesn't make sense for a scout without armour.

Which is the "generally accepted" way to write this if I want other Haskellers to be able to understand and follow my code?

Comment: I get what you're asking, but as a side note, your code above is not legal and would not compile. Scout and Tank are different constructors of the same type Unit - you can't define separate instances for each *constructor*. Are you intending to use the DataKinds extension?

Comment: You can also read my answer to a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17100055/1026598).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most Haskell programmers frown on needless typeclasses. These hurt type inference; you can't even make a list of `Unit`s without tricks; in GHC, there's all the secret dictionary passing; they somehow make the Haddocks harder to read; they can lead to brittle hierarchies ... maybe others can give you further reasons. I guess a good rule would be to use them when it's much more painful to avoid them. For instance, without `Eq`, you'd have to manually pass around the functions to compare, say, two `[[[Int]]]`s (or use some ad-hoc runtime tests), which is one of the pain points of ML programming.

Take a look at [this blog post](https://lukepalmer.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/haskell-antipattern-existential-typeclass/). Your first method of using a sum type is OK, but if you want to allow users to mod the game with new units or whatever, I'd suggest something like

```
data Unit = Unit { name :: String, maxHealth :: Int }

scout, tank :: Unit
scout = Unit { name = "scout", maxHealth = 10 }
tank  = Unit { name = "tank",  maxHealth = 20 }

allUnits = [ scout
           , tank
           , Unit { name = "another unit", maxHealth = 5 }
           ]
```

In your example, you need to encode somewhere that a tank has armor but a scout doesn't. The obvious possibility is to augment the Unit type with extra information like a `Maybe Armor` field or a list of special powers ... there's not necessarily a definitive way.

One heavyweight solution, probably overkill, is to use a library like Vinyl that provides extensible records, giving you a form of subtyping.

Comment: You didn't even bother to copy the link when you copied and pasted from [my corresponding question on reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/1j0awq/definitive_guide_on_when_to_use_typeclasses/). For shame :P

Comment: @jmite: Fixed, sorry.

Answer (score 3):

I tend to use typeclasses only when generating and passing around the instances manually becomes a big mess.  In the code I write this is almost never.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not going to weigh in on an answer to a definitive time to use typeclasses, but I am currently writing a library that uses both of the methods you described for your Unit class. I lean on the sum type generally, but there's one large advantage that the typeclass method has: it gives you *type-level* distinctions between your `Unit`s.

This forces you to write to your interface slightly more as any function that needs to be polymorphic over `Unit`s must use only functions defined, ultimately, on the your abstract typeclass basis. In my case, it also importantly lets me use `Unit`-type types as type parameters in phantom types.

For instance, I'm writing a Haskell binding to [Nanomsg](http://nanomsg.org/) (a ZMQ-alike project from the original author of ZMQ). In Nanomsg you have `Socket` types which share representations and semantics. Each `Socket`s has exactly one `Protocol` and some functions can only be called on `Socket`s of a particular `Protocol`. I could have these functions throw errors or return `Maybe`s, but instead I defined my `Protocol`s as separate types all sharing a class.

```
class Protocol p where ...

data Protocol1 = Protocol1
data Protocol2 = Protocol2

instance Protocol Protocol1 where ...
instance Protocol Protocol2 where ...
```

and have `Socket`s have a phantom type parameter

```
newtype Socket p = Socket ...
```

And now I can make it a type error to call functions on the wrong protocols.

```
funOnProto1 :: Socket Protocol1 -> ...
```

whereas if `Socket` were just a sum type this would be impossible to check at compile time.

Comment: Just to point out: phantom types/GADTs don't require this style of programming - you could achieve equal safety with the typeclass-free "direct style" advocated in the blog post I link to in my answer.

Comment: That's true. I didn't well compare against the direct style, just the coproduct style. In my own application, direct style felt like it'd be annoying, so I went with a class. We'll see if I keep it.