# What brings a bigger performance hit: currying or typeclasses?

Tags: haskell

I am debating whether I should use typeclasses or just create partial applications with all necessary functions curried in.

```
processWith validate accept reject x xs = if validate x then accept x xs else reject x xs
process = processWith (> 0) (\x xs -> x:xs) (\x _ -> error "Unexpected x: " ++ show x)
```

As far as I understand conceptually it's just a matter of [personal taste](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17100036/should-i-use-typeclasses-or-not) which way to go. Now I am wondering about the performance implications of using currying over typeclasses.

Comment: The performance implications of either are going to indistinguishable in many cases. GHC is designed to use both efficiently and you may often find that they compile into very similar Core.

Comment: I think you're talking about abstracting out some repeated patterns or boilerplate in your code using higher-order functions, which is really common. There's not enough information here to know if a typeclass would make sense for you, but choosing one or the other based on performance concerns is way premature optimization.

Comment: @jberryman, personally I don't see any good reason why anyone would use typeclasses. However I can see how awkward they are when it is necessary to have more than one instance for a given type. But going all the way giving up on using them in favor of specifying functions explicitly may or may not turn out to be a bad idea without knowing details of how they were implemented and what considerations authors of Haskell had for adding typeclasses to the language.

Comment: @AlekseyBykov: in many cases, there is _only one meaningful way_ to have an instance for a given type (you may want to specify the type class laws that narrow it down to this choice). In this case, type classes get you rid of dictionary arguments which are nothing but boilerplate; that's doubtlessly a good thing. Even when there are multiple possibilities, choosing between them with `newtype` wrappers is often more effective than with explicit method passing, e.g. in safety regards: if you're using more than one operation of a given class in a row, `newtype` makes sure the instances match.

Answer (score 5):

Well, the crucial difference: with type classes you'll generally achieve more concise code whereas the explicit dictionary functions are more flexible.

But you can't say either is more performant. In general, type classes are simply implemented as an implicit dictionary argument, so basically syntactic sugar for your second alternative. In performance-critical cases, GHC should often be able to inline any extra calls, then neither way really as a "performance hit" at all. The good thing about type classes is that you can use `{-# SPECIALISE instance #-}` pragmas to help this inlining in quite an easy way; doing that with explicitly-passed dictionaries using `{-# INLINABLE #-}` tends to be rather more cumbersome. But then, again explicit is more general so you may find it easier to optimise a particular call with a priori unforseen combinations.

Conclusion: the best thing probably is to privide both, a version with dictionary argument and a typeclass-method equivalent. This is also done for many standard library routines.

Comment: "This is also done for many standard library routines." can you give some examples?

Comment: I believe @leftroundabout is talking about the "By" functions and their corresponding typeclass equivalent. See http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Data-List.html#v:nub and http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Data-List.html#v:nubBy