# When to use typeclasses?

Tags: haskell

Usually when I create functions I don't know in which functions it is better to use typeclasses (`Eq`,`Integral` and etc.) because sometimes there is no need to use them like:

```
factorial :: Int -> Int 
bla bla bla 
bla bla bla
```

and

```
factorial :: (Integral a) => a -> a
bla bla bla
bla bla bla
```

I believe that the second one is just taking time and place 
but in elem function it is important to write `Eq` (below `elleme` is `elem`)

```
elemme :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Bool
y `elemme` [] = False
y `elemme` (x:xs) = if y == x then True else y `elemme` xs
```

Please advise me something about it. Thanks.

Comment: This may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17100036/should-i-use-typeclasses-or-not?rq=1

Comment: Think about function/args properties. What properties do you want on your function/args?. First, understand about properties (`Eq`, `Ord`, `Monoid`, ...) then, you can restrict your functions to work *with arguments (compliance) properties* (instead of explicit arguments like `Int`, `Bool`, ...).

Comment: `factorial` is actually a bad example, because if you use `Int` instead of `Integer` it gives the wrong answer for any number higher than 20.

Comment: @JeremyList arguably, yes. But there are still probably _some_ use cases for something like that... forgive me if I can't think of them on the top of my head, but I'm sure they're there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the benefits I get out of making my functions as general as possible is that it often allows for use cases I didn't think of before. When you start making things general, you start coming up with weird uses for your functions.

You go, "But what if this value is a function?" Or "What if I allow this for any functor – what would be the result for other functors? Is it useful?" As it turns out, it *is* in a lot of cases! And this is one of the reasons Haskell is so great, in my opinion. It is easy to "accidentally" create very reusable functions.

In other languages, you design functions for specific purposes and use them that way. In Haskell, you design functions for specific purposes and give them a general type signature, and suddenly they work for a ton of cases you didn't design them for.

---

@jozefg made a great point about the generality restricting the possible implementations. I just want to give that more of a spotlight, because it is actually a very powerful concept. With a few general function, you can actually be completely sure what the function does only based on the type signature, because there's only one possible implementation for that general signature.

I recently encountered the signature

```
mystery :: (a -> b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
```

which is interesting because we can actually figure out which function it is based on what it does. We have

```
mystery :: (a -> b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
mystery    f                g           x = ...
```

and we need it to return  a `c` value of some kind. The only way we can get a value of type `c` is by applying the function `f` to an `a` value and a `b` value. We already have a single `a` value – this is the `x` argument. So we can partially apply `f x :: b -> c` but we still need a `b` value to get the `c` value we want.

The solution, of course, is to apply `g x` to get a `b` value, which we then can stick into `f`, thus finally returning a `c` value. The description of this is a little complicated to follow, but if you work it out in your head you arrive at

```
mystery f g x = f x (g x)
```

which performs the same thing as the library function `ap`. (From `Control.Applicative`.)

It is *very* cool that you can figure out what a function does solely based on its type signature!

Answer (score 9):

Typeclasses let you write more general functions. Haskell has great tools for letting you specify that a function works over all types, like

```
id :: a -> a
id a = a
```

But some things don't work over all types,

```
(==) :: Eq a => a -> a -> Bool
```

Without typeclasses, we'd either have to write a new `==` for each type,

```
eqInteger :: Integer -> Integer -> Bool
```

Or specify that all types are equatable and can be tested for equality. But then you could ask

```
id == const 1
```

So, when you find yourself wanting to specify that your function works over a subset of all types, go for typeclasses.

I often favor writing this more general functions even if I don't use them over more than one type since the more general the signature, the fewer options there are for the implementation, which makes it easier to know that I haven't done something silly like

```
id :: Integer -> Integer
id = (+1)
```

You're essentially stating that your function only requires X functions which makes it possible to get a compiler error for using the wrong function.