# Haskell: Typeclass vs passing a function

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, higher-order-functions

To me it seems that you can always pass function arguments rather than using a typeclass. For example rather than defining equality typeclass:

```
class Eq a where 
  (==)                  :: a -> a -> Bool
```

And using it in other functions to indicate type argument must be an instance of `Eq`:

```
elem                    :: (Eq a) => a -> [a] -> Bool
```

Can't we just define our `elem` function without using a typeclass and instead pass a function argument that does the job?

Comment: that's called dictionary passing. You can think typeclass constraints as implicit arguments.

Comment: You could do that, but it's obviously much more convenient to not have to pass a function and just have it use a "standard" one depending on the type.

Comment: @RobinZigmond yes. So it's what I thought: Convenience. Rather than allowing the developer to do something that was not possible before, it just makes things easier

Comment: You could put it like that, yes. But I'd argue that there is at least one other important advantage: the ability to write polymorphic functions which work on any type which implements a particular "interface" or set of features. I think typeclass constraints express that very clearly in a way that passing extra function arguments doesn't. In particular because of the (sadly implicit) "laws" which many typeclasses have to satisfy. A `Monad m` constraint says more to me than passing additional function arguments of types `a -> m a` and `m a -> (a ->  m b) -> m b`.

Comment: See also [are typeclasses essential?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25855507/are-typeclasses-essential)

Comment: The `TypeApplications` extension lets you make the implicit argument explicit.  `(==) @Int 3 5` compares `3` and `5` specifically as `Int` values. You can think of `@Int` as a key in the dictionary of type-specific equality functions, rather than the `Int`-specific comparison function itself.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes.  This is called "dictionary passing style".  Sometimes when I am doing some especially tricky things, I need to scrap a typeclass and turn it into a dictionary, because dictionary passing is more powerful<sup>1</sup>, yet often quite cumbersome, making conceptually simple code look quite complicated.  I use dictionary passing style sometimes in languages that aren't Haskell to simulate typeclasses (but have learned that that is usually not as great an idea as it sounds).

Of course, whenever there is a difference in expressive power, there is a trade-off.  While you can use a given API in more ways if it is written using DPS, the API gets more information if you can't.  One way this shows up in practice is in `Data.Set`, which relies on the fact that there is only one `Ord` dictionary per type.  The `Set` stores its elements sorted according to `Ord`, and if you build a set with one dictionary, and then inserted an element using a different one, as would be possible with DPS, you could break `Set`'s invariant and cause it to crash.  This uniqueness problem can be mitigated using a [phantom existential](https://kataskeue.com/gdp.pdf) type to mark the dictionary, but, again, at the cost of quite a bit of annoying complexity in the API.  This also shows up in pretty much the same way in the `Typeable` API.

The uniqueness bit doesn't come up very often.  What typeclasses are great at is writing code for you.  For example,

```
catProcs :: (i -> Maybe String) -> (i -> Maybe String) -> (i -> Maybe String)
catProcs f g = f <> g
```

which takes two "processors" which take an input and might give an output, and concatenates them, flattening away `Nothing`, would have to be written in DPS something like this:

```
catProcs f g = (<>) (funcSemi (maybeSemi listSemi)) f g
```

We essentially had to spell out the type we're using it at again, even though we already spelled it out in the type signature, and even that was redundant because the compiler already knows all the types.  Because there's only one way to construct a given `Semigroup` at a type, the compiler can do it for you.  This has a "compound interest" type effect when you start defining a lot of parametric instances and using the structure of your types to compute for you, as in the [`Data.Functor.*`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0) combinators, and this is used to great effect with [`deriving via`](https://www.kosmikus.org/DerivingVia/deriving-via-paper.pdf) where you can essentially get all the "standard" algebraic structure of your type written for you.

And don't even get me started on MPTC's and fundeps, which feed information back into typechecking and inference.  I have never tried converting such a thing to DPS -- I suspect it would involve passing around a lot of type equality proofs -- but in any case I'm sure it would be a lot more work for my brain than I would be comfortable with.

--

<sup>1</sup>U*nless you use [`reflection`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/reflection) in which case they become equivalent in power -- but `reflection` can also be cumbersome to use.*

Comment: Might be worth mentioning [Winant and Devriese 2018: Coherent explicit dictionary application for Haskell](https://doi.org/10.1145/3242744.3242752)

Comment: I am very interested in fundeps expressed through DPS. Do you know some recommandable resources on this subject? Anyway, very comprehensable explanation.

Comment: @bob, not offhand, but it would be an interesting exploration.  Maybe ask a new question about it?

Answer (score 5):

Yes. That (called dictionary passing) is basically what the compiler does to typeclasses anyway. For that function, done literally, it would look a bit like this:

```
elemBy :: (a -> a -> Bool) -> a -> [a] -> Bool
elemBy _ _ [] = False
elemBy eq x (y:ys) = eq x y || elemBy eq x ys
```

Calling `elemBy (==) x xs` is now equivalent to `elem x xs`. And in this specific case, you can go a step further: `eq` has the same first argument every time, so you can make it the caller's responsibility to apply that, and end up with this:

```
elemBy2 :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool
elemBy2 _ [] = False
elemBy2 eqx (y:ys) = eqx y || elemBy2 eqx ys
```

Calling `elemBy2 (x ==) xs` is now equivalent to `elem x xs`.

...Oh wait. That's just [`any`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:any). (And in fact, [in the standard library, `elem = any . (==)`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/Data.Foldable.html#elem).)

Comment: AFAIU dictionary passing is Scala's approach to encoding type classes. Those extra arguments can be declared as `implicit` and the compiler would inject them for you from the scope.